# Returning a column of a table where the value of that column is at least as big as all the rows of that column

Tags: sql

I need to return the name of all employees whose years of employment are at least as long as the employment years of all the other employees.

I have the following table

Employees

```
identification_number     first_name     employment_years
---------------------------------------------------------
         20               Peter                 50
         21               Edward                37
         22               Elizabeth             22
         23               Katherine             46
```

For someone to have at least as many employment years as everybody else, the years of employment column row should should be larger or equal to the others, I therefor tried the following query.

```
SELECT first_name
FROM   Employees E
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   Employees E1, Employees E2
                   WHERE  E1.employment_years >= E2.employment_years)
```

But this gives me no results at all. The result should give me the name Peter, as he has worked the most years in this group of employees. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way uses `ALL`:

```
select e.*
from employees e
where e.employment_years >= all (select e2.employment_years
                                 from employees e2
                                );
```

You can use `not exists` as:

```
select e.*
from employees e
where not exists (select 1
                  from employees e2
                  where e2.employment_years > e.employment_years
                 );
```

Comment: good morning Gordon , since I always see you here , I felt I should say hi

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply Gordon! Is there also a way to use NOT EXISTS, as I'm not familiar with the use of ALL?